cameraController.stopVideoRecording() return XFile with .temp extension which should be mp4 and save to gallery
this is video recorder app, so videoRecording should be started immidiately that's why i have called startCamera method.
when video recording completes client clicks on stop recording button, then stopRecording method triggers,
after that i get XFile .
my problem is
when i print path it shows
I/flutter (11116): Inside Recording stopped /data/user/0/com.example.design4you/cache/REC7110041240717347649.temp

the extension expected is mp4 but i get temp,
also i want to send this video through API and save a copy on device(gallery) also.
this is my full code:-
 void initState() {
    print('Inside initState');
    startCamera();
    super.initState();
  }



 void startCamera() async {
    print('Inside startCamera');
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[1], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    cameraValue = cameraController.initialize();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    startRecording();
  }



 void startRecording() async {
    print('Inside startRecording');

    try {
      print('Inside startRecording Try block');

      //Starts recording video
      await cameraValue;
      await cameraController.prepareForVideoRecording();

      await cameraController.startVideoRecording();
    } catch (e) {
      print("inside catch error message" + e.toString());
      Get.snackbar('title', e.toString());
    }

   
  }

  void stopRecording() async {
    print('Inside stop recording');
    XFile video = await cameraController.stopVideoRecording();

    print('Inside Recording stopped ' + video.path);

    Get.snackbar('video.path', video.path);

    try {
      await Gal.putVideo(video.path);
    } catch (e) {
      print("inside Catch" + e.toString());
    }
  }

and this is output of debug console
I/flutter (11116): Inside initState
I/flutter (11116): Inside startCamera
I/flutter (11116): Inside startRecording
I/flutter (11116): Inside startRecording Try block
I/flutter (11116): Inside stop recording
I/flutter (11116): Inside Recording stopped /data/user/0/com.example.design4you/cache/REC7110041240717347649.temp
I/flutter (11116): inside [GalException/UNEXPECTED]: An unexpected error has occurred.

help is apriciated.

the exention is totally irrelavant as is is a temporary file anyway that you probably have to copy to the location you want it to be saved. Have you verified that the created file does contain the video by transferring it to a place you can access it and renaming it to mp4?

You need to renmae your file with .mp4 extension.
fully working code
void stopRecording() async {
    print('Inside stop recording');
    XFile video = await cameraController.stopVideoRecording();

    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final String tempPath = video.path;
    final String newFileName =
        path.join(tempDir.path, '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4');
    final File tempFile = File(tempPath);
    final File newFile = tempFile.renameSync(newFileName);

    print('Inside Recording stopped ' + video.path);

    try {
      await Gal.putVideo(newFile.path);
      print('Inside Try');
    } catch (e) {
      print("inside Catch" + e.toString());
    }
  }

if you still face any error,reply with debug console output.
